# Convert from URL encoding to UTF-8

Tags: java, string, utf-8, ascii

I'm trying to convert from a URL-encoded ASCII byte array to UTF-8 in Java.

The input ASCII string `Fa%C3%A7ade` should be converted to the output UTF-8 string `Façade`.

Comment: icza is right, your input isn't ASCII and there is not need to convert ASCII to UTF-8 because it is a subset of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input string is not ASCII but a URL-encoded string.

You can decode it like this:

```
String s = "Fa%C3%A7ade";
System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(s, "UTF-8"));
```

A `String` in Java is represented as a character array (`char[]`), it is not encoded in any encoding. Encoding comes into play when a `String` is converted to a byte array or a byte array is converted to a `String`.

So if you have a byte array which is a `String` encoded using UTF-8 encoding, you can convert it to a `String` like this:

```
byte[] arr = {104, 101, 108, 108, 111};
String s = new String(arr, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(s); // Prints "hello"

// Or your input string would be:
arr = {70, 97, -61, -89, 97, 100, 101};
s = new String(arr, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(s); // Prints "Façade"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
new String (bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Apache commons-codec**

```
byte[] bytes = StringUtils.getBytesUtf8(asciiString);
String utfString = new String(bytes);
```